# RxJS BehaviouSubject when using map operator in service and subscribing in the component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I am new to BehaviourSubject in RxJS and I am trying to use it to share data across components. I am not sure how exactly to use it. The code in my component is

```
export class CarsListComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: Cars[] = []; 
  constructor(private carsListService: CarsListService) { }


     ngOnInit() {
       this.carsListService.getCars()
      .subscribe(response => {
      this.cars= response;
      }, error => {
       console.log(error);
      });
     }
}
```

The code in my service is

```
 export class CarsService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 getCars(): Observable<Car[]> {
    return this.http.get<Car[]>(url,headers)
    .pipe(
        map(response => response)
    );
 }
}
```

I don't know how to use BehaviourSubject and how to implement it. Please help me out with this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Why do you want to use a `BehaviourSubject`?

Comment: are you looking to cache the http result or something?

Comment: Have a read about a library I wrote call RxCache for this exact sort of thing. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question i think you are trying to use the same `this.cars` across multiple components . If you want to share it then using `BehaviorSubject` is one way to do it as it stores the value even if already subscribed to it.

Let's create a shared service that will be injected into multiple components say `app-shared.service.ts`

`app-shared.service.ts` :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject , Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppSharedService {

  carsListSubjectt : BehaviorSubject<Cars[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Cars[]>([]);

  constructor() { }


  updateCarsList(cars : Cars[]) : void{
    this.carsListSubjectt.next(cars);
  }


  getCarsList() : Observable<Cars[]>{
    return this.carsListSubjectt.asObservable();
  }

}



export interface Cars{
  carType : string ;
  manufacturedDate : Date;
  condition : string;
}
```

**Note :** `Cars` interface is just my definition . Use your definition .

Now you just have to `inject` the `app-shared.service` in your required component.

To update data , using your code :

```
export class CarsListComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: Cars[] = []; 
  constructor(private carsListService: CarsListService, private _appSharedService : AppSharedService) { }


     ngOnInit() {
       this.carsListService.getCars()
      .subscribe(response => {
      this.cars= response;
      this._appSharedService.updateCarsList(response);
      }, error => {
       console.log(error);
      });
     }
}
```

You just have to subscribe to the `getCarsList()` defined in the `app-shared.service` as it is going to return an `Observable<Cars[]>` .

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: @CruelEngineThanks for the response. Yes I am trying to share same data across multiple components. Now the scenario is I make one API call to fetch the entire list when the application loads and the list component page is loaded. I need to cache this data. Now when I go to car details component and make any changes, the cached data should be updated and the list page should load from updated cached data. So we should make API call once only when app loads. Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: @suvenk yes it is possible. You'll have to update the data in the list and then call ``this._appSharedService.updateCarsList()`` again by passing the updated list.

Comment: @CruelEngineConsider that we update the data in the list using the second component and call this._appSharedService.updateCarsList() from the second component to update the list. Now when we navigate back to first component the getCars() which is inside ngOnInit() is again called. So how can we avoid calling it and instead use the cached updated data?

Comment: @suvenk one way is to use ``takeWhile()`` for your ``getCars()`` . not sure if it is the right way . This is an interesting implementation . Its better if you can ask another question for this requirement .

Answer (score 0):

In the service you can use shareReplay

```
cars$ = this.http.get<Car[]>(url,headers).pipe(
  shareReplay()
);
```

Use the async pipe

```
cars$ = this.carsListService.cars$;
```

and in the template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cars$ | async as cars">
  Do stuff with cars here
  {{ cars | json }}
</ng-container>
```

No need for subscriptions and unsubscribing